# popping up an AlertDialog on click a button in a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-cursoradapter

I have ListView that is populated using a CursorAdapter. In each ListView row there are too textviews and a button. An AlerDialog is supposed to pop on button click.The AlertDiaog itself is filled with a cursor.
the problem is that when i try to make and alert dialog builder it needs an argument that i don't know how to get it. the code that i"m posting here has a syntax error that i don't know how to fix it. 
i tried to move the ItemClickListener to original activity class but the button has null value when i try to assign it to an object. 
this is the bindView of the CursorAdapter:

```
    public void bindView(final View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    //ListView list= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.words);
    Button addButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view1) {
            //Dictionary d=new Dictionary();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Dictionary.this); // the error
            final Cursor boxes=Dictionary.getCursor();
            builder.setCursor(boxes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Dictionary.getCursor().moveToPosition(i);
                    String text = boxes.getString(boxes.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    Log.d("select", "onClick: "+text);

                }
            }, "name");
            builder.show();
        }
    });
    TextView english=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.english);
    TextView farsi=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.farsi);
    english.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    farsi.setText(cursor.getString(2));
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a `Context` (which you are passing into the `bindView` method) to the `AlertDialog.Builder()`. 
See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder(android.content.Context)

Comment: what context exactly? like getApplicationContext() ?? because i tried it and it generates an exception. @chrjs

Comment: Like I said, you already have the `context` passed as a variable into the `bindView` method. So just you could just pass it on. 

`AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);`

Comment: i tried it and it throws this one : android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application @chrjs

Comment: You're not calling `builder.create()` before your `.show()` and I believe you have to pass in the Fragment Manager and a String tag to `.show()`